# "Unable to connect to the remote server" for localhost

Tags: c#, http, web, websocket, localhost

I have two applications. AppA is trying to make a connections (ports are opened) to AppB. I am sure (checked during Debug and also see in tasklist) that AppA is reaching proper port, but there is an exception thrown: "Unable to connect to the remote server"

```
WS = new ClientWebSocket();
WS.Options.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(seconds: 120, days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0);
if (CTS != null) CTS.Dispose();
CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
try {
    WS.ConnectAsync(uri: new Uri(url), cancellationToken: CTS.Token).Wait();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect: " + e.Message);
    return;
}
```

Besides opening a port, how can I Debug the situation? What to check? I am new in web development.

Comment: Can you connect using a tool like postman?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are debugging both applications while testing or they are deployed to your local IIS. It could be something as simple as forgetting to run the application with the endpoint you are trying to hit.